# Javascript - Create a map with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a Google Maps API call with the URL below and would like to know how to generate and embed the map in HTML using the callback data?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua+Amarilis,134+Palho%C3%A7a&key=AIzaSyC-9XzfWIRagerL60bVUzOpPlpZgmL-4n0&sensor=false

Comment: can u please post what are all the things you tried

Comment: That is a webservice call.  To embed a map, use the Embed API or (more complicated) the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON data will not display the map. If you want to display the map you have to write Google Map API to intercept the JSON data.
Use this as a reference -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Or you can use Embed API,
use this as a reference - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start